# unable to perform string input/output in c++, Netbean

Tags: c++, netbeans

I'm new to C++ and is trying to input/output strings. This is the code I had.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string s;
    cin >> s;
    cout << s << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However, when I tried to compile it, the compiler output:

```
warning: using directive refers to implicitly-defined namespace 'std'
using namespace std;
                ^

error: unknown type name 'string'
    string id;
    ^
```

Due to my limited knowledge, I have not been able to solve the problem. I have written similar code before and it used to work just fine. Could someone please help me out? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What do you have inside **cin**?

Comment: If NetBeans lets you, open up one of the header files (right click the name and look for an option). You might need a reinstall or something if those aren't proper.

Comment: You can read this... http://www.digitalnoiz.com/c-cpp/c-cpp-errors/error-main-cpp-warning-using-directive-refers-to-implicitly-defined-namespace-std/

Comment: @MukitChowdhury, *You can fix this warning by including a C++ header file that uses a std namespace* - which is what the OP did.

Comment: I've compiled and run your code successfully on NB8.1. Can you compile this file from commandline? Just to check if your compiler is right. Btw. what version of Netbeans are you using?

Comment: Another thing: The warning comes from a **`string id`** - but in your code there's none ...